# copying value of object a to object b without disturbing not null value in c#

Tags: c#, object

I have two object of same class say Obj1 and Obj2 if same class.Obj1 contain some values and same for other.
for example

```
class book 
{
   public string science {get;set;} 
   public string math {get;set;}
   public string drawing {get;set;}
   public string english {get;set;}
}
```

Obj1 contains drawing, math and science value.
Obj2 contains math and english value.

I want to copy Obj1 to Obj2 in such a way that Obj2 gets drawing,science value and also replace math value by value in Obj1 and also english value of Obj2  is preserved.

This is just sample real project contains more than 60 property in class so i don't want to do like Obj2.drawing=Obj1.drawing,Obj2.math=Obj1.math and soon .I need to do that without mentioning property name like math,drawing....

---

In summary I need to copy value of Obj1 to Obj2 and only those value which are in Obj1 are replace in Obj2, null value of Obj1 should not replace values in Obj2.
Is that be possible.If yes then please guide me.

Comment: Maybe the design of your class needs to change. Try using a `Dictionary`.

Comment: You have several ways to do this. What are you having troubles with? Maybe we can help better if you show what you have tried

Answer (score 3):

AutoMapper to the resque!

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Book, Book>()
    .ForAllMembers(opt => opt.Condition(srs => !srs.IsSourceValueNull));

var b1 = new Book { P1 = null, P2 = "b1p2" };
var b2 = new Book { P1 = "b2p1", P2 = "b2p2" };

Mapper.Map(b1, b2);

Assert.IsNotNull(b2.P1);
```

Comment: Mapper means what from where i is derive

Comment: @ConfuseD, sorry, I cann't parse your comment, could you reformulate it?

Answer (score 1):

You could have an instance based copy function that checks for null before assigning the value over:

```
public class book
{
    public string science { get; set; }
    public string math { get; set; }
    public string drawing { get; set; }
    public string english { get; set; }

    public book()
    {
    }

    public void CopyTo(book other)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.science))
            other.science = this.science;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.math))
            other.math = this.math;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.drawing))
            other.drawing = this.drawing;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.english))
            other.english = this.english;
    }
}
```

Example:

```
var foo = new book();
foo.science = "foo1";
foo.math = "foo2";
foo.drawing = "foo3";
foo.english = null;

var bar = new book();
bar.science = "bar1";
bar.math = "bar2";
bar.drawing = "bar3";
bar.english = "bar4";

foo.CopyTo(bar);

Console.WriteLine(bar.science);
Console.WriteLine(bar.math);
Console.WriteLine(bar.drawing);
Console.WriteLine(bar.english);

Console.Read();
```

This will ensure that the `null` value of the property `foo.english` isn't copied to the associated property of the `bar` obj.

Giving the output:

> foo1
>   foo2
>   foo3
>   bar4

Comment: CopyTo didn't  recognize

Comment: then i have to check !string.IsNullOrEmpty for all properties which is too lengthly

Comment: What do you mean it _"didn't recognize"_? Did you add it to your `book` class? If the class in your OP is just an example you should state that in the question, I have no idea of the scope of what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a Dictionary instead. It has these methods:

```
Add(String key, String value)
TryGetValue(String key, out String value)
```

You can also use them like an array, just put a string in the square brackets.

```
String x = dictionary["x"];
```

An example of what you might be wanting to do:

```
var books = new Dictionary<String, String>();
books.Add("Science", "Sciencey stuff goes in here!");
books.Add("English", "How now brown cow");
Console.WriteLine(books["English"]);

// Now lets assume you want to add one set of books to another
foreach(KeyValuePair<String, String> book in books1)
    if (!books2.ContainsKey(book.Key))
        books2.Add(book.Key, book.Value);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use System.Reflection for this. But it is slow, much slower than just obj2.drawing = obj1.drawing. Here is code:

```
    public static void CopyNotNulls<T>(T source, T dest)
    {
        var type = typeof(T);
        var properties = type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
            .Where(p => p.PropertyType.IsClass)
            .ToArray();
        foreach (var property in properties)
        {
            var val = property.GetValue(source);
            if (val == null)
            {
                continue;
            }
            property.SetValue(dest, val);
        }
    }
```

Comment: did you add  `using System.Reflection;` to you cs file?

Comment: or do you use a value type(defined as `struct { }`?

Answer (score 0):

```
class book 
{
   public string science {get;set;} 
   public string math {get;set;}
   public string drawing {get;set;}
   public string english {get;set;}
}
```

Assume you have `Obj1` and `Obj2` like:

```
var Obj1 = new book() { science = "molecules", math = "sin(x)", drawing = "brush" };
var Obj2 = new book() { math = "cos(y)", english = "Shakespeare" };
```

Fist you have to get every property of your `Obj1`. then read every property's value inside `for` loop, save it in the `ValueRead` variable. check if `ValueRead` is not `null`, then copy it to `Obj2`.

```
foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in Obj1.GetType().GetProperties())
{
    var ValueRead = Obj1.GetType().GetProperty(propertyInfo.Name).GetValue(Obj1, null);
    if (ValueRead != null)
        Obj2.GetType().GetProperty(propertyInfo.Name).SetValue(Obj2, ValueRead, null);
}
```

`Obj2` will be like:

```
{science = "molecules", math = "cos(y)", drawing = "brush", english = "Shakespeare" }
```